# JPQL: Get count from custom NEW Object

Tags: java, mysql, jpql

Hi please help to make correct JPQL-request.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT NEW api.custom.ProductPop(b.productId, SUM(b.price)) 
FROM Base b GROUP BY b.productId ORDER BY SUM(b.price) DESC
```

It works correctly. As a result like you can see I have a table with two columns `productId` and `price`

How to get count of rows in this table (`api.custom.ProductPop`) ?

Comment: Run the query, you get a `List` and use `size()` on it?

Comment: Yes, tnx, it is a simple way, but I have several millions rows and make this request 0-20 times per second, I don't want to load all these objects to memory. I would prefer to get just one <long> value.

Comment: Then count all distinct `productId`, no?

Comment: I think so but I really don't understand how to make it.
Of course it isn't correct:
SELECT COUNT (n.productId) FROM NEW api.custom.ProductPop(b.productId, SUM(b.price)) n
FROM Base b GROUP BY b.productId ORDER BY SUM(b.price) DESC